# How to delete content (messages) from Listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, treeviewitem

I have Listbox with Listboxitems in this form:

```
<ListBoxItem Height="Auto">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Sender"/>
        <Label Content="Subject"/>
        <Label Content="mail@sender.com"/>
        <Label Visibility="Collapsed">Random text from random sender.</Label>
    </StackPanel> 
</ListBoxItem>
```

I want to do that when I press button DELETE (name = delete_bt) my this whole message from Listboxitem should be moved to DELETED MESSAGES folder (which is subtree in treeview):

```
<TreeViewItem Header="DELETED MESSAGES"/>
```

Also I would like to do that when I move to that folder I will be able to delete message using DELETE button permanently.

Comment: what is listbox bound to ? remove item from that and move to deleted messages list

Comment: @Muds Everything is inside GRID. Well i have some thing like that, on left part of screen TreeView with Recieved, sent and deleted messages, and on left side that Listbox with "messages". Under listbox is Textblock, where these messages from Collapsed Label are shown. I hope you understood me, or I can get some print screen tho.
I want to click on that Stack panel and when I press DELETE button everything should be moved under TreeViewItem -> Deleted messages.

Comment: what is items source to that tree view ?

Comment: @Muds Well I guess there is no source? Sorry I am beginner and my english is a little bit bad. Well I made everything in WPF Project aka XAML layout and now I am trying in C# to move those messages to deleted folder via button.

Comment: its ok, I meant, what is parent to the item that you want to move ? that control will have an itemsSource property, whatever itemsSource is, you should move objects in that

Comment: @Muds Well parent to ListBoxItem in which is that message is ListBox if thats what are you asking me?

Comment: Paste more xaml code , that should clarify

Comment: @Muds http://pastebin.com/Ltuhcz53
I hope that will help at my explanation.